# Как можно после прокрутки вниз определить текущую строку в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtablewidget

Есть таблица `QTableWidget` со строками и полоса прокрутки справа.

Как можно после прокрутки вниз определить текущую строку?

Методы `tableWidget.currentRow()` и `tableWidget.currentItem()` здесь вероятно не подойдут?

Answer (score 2):

Извините, но я не понял, как вы связываете полосу прокрутки с текущей строкой? 
Класс `QTableWidget` имеет достаточно сигналов, чтобы определить элемент ячейки и подсказать, что с ним происходит. Посмотрите пример ниже, там реализованы некоторые с сигналы.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App,self).__init__()
        self.data  = [1,2,3,4,5]

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 5)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['V1','V2','V3','V4','V5']) 
        self.table.setMouseTracking(True)

        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        # Этот сигнал испускается при каждом щелчке ячейки в таблице.
        self.table.cellClicked[int, int].connect(self.clickedRowColumn)    

        # Этот сигнал испускается, когда ячейка, указанная в строке и столбце, активирована
        self.table.cellActivated[int, int].connect(self.activatedRowColumn)

        # Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда данные элемента в ячейке изменяются.
        self.table.cellChanged[int, int].connect(self.changedRowColumn)    

        # Этот сигнал испускается, когда курсор мыши входит в ячейку. 
        self.table.cellEntered[int, int].connect(self.enteredRowColumn)
        # -------------------------------------------------------------

        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.btn_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить строку')

        self.btn_add.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_add)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def activatedRowColumn(self, r, c):
        self.lbl.setText("Активная: строка->`{}`, столбец->`{}`, ячейка->`<b> {} : {}</b> `".format(r, c, r, c,))

    def changedRowColumn(self, r, c):
        self.lbl.setText("Изменились данные ячейки->`<b> {} : {}<b>`".format(r, c,))

    def clickedRowColumn(self, r, c):
        self.lbl.setText("<b>Вы кликнули ячейку->`<i style='color:blue'> {} : {} </i>`</b>".format(r, c,))

    def enteredRowColumn(self, r, c):
        self.lbl.setText("<b>Курсор мыши в ячейкe->`<i style='color:red'> {} : {} </i>`</b>".format(r, c,))        

    def add_row(self):
        rowPosition = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.insertRow(rowPosition)
        for i in range(5):
            self.table.setItem(rowPosition, 
                                      i, 
                                      QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data[i])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за хороший пример. Но мне нужно немного другое. Нужно листать например по 10 строк вниз по нажатию кнопки. Текущей ячейка станет после нажатия на ней, но я могу и не нажимать, а просто прокрутить полосу прокрутки вниз и нужно будет листать с текущей видимой строки

Comment: у меня событие cellEntered[int, int].connect(self.enteredRowColumn) как-то неправильно работает - когда курсор входит в ячейку ничего не происходит, а срабатывает если удерживаешь левую кнопку мыши и вводишь в ячейку. Почему так?

Comment: Этот сигнал испускается, когда курсор мыши входит в ячейку. Ячейка задается строкой и столбцом. Этот сигнал выдается только при включении мыши, или при нажатии кнопки мыши при перемещении в элемент. Добавьте `self.table.setMouseTracking(True)`

Comment: Спасибо братец. Попробую

Comment: @MyNick скажите пожалуйста этот вопрос решен?

Comment: Я уже не помню, по-моему нет